# How to remove inner quotes from the style attribute using regEx

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove all inner quotes from style attribute:

```
<span style="color: rgb(34 , 34 , 34) ; font-family: "arial" , "verdana" , "helvetica" , sans-serif ; font-size: 15.33px ; font-weight: normal" >
```

What I need:

```
<span style="color: rgb(34 , 34 , 34) ; font-family: arial , verdana , helvetica , sans-serif ; font-size: 15.33px ; font-weight: normal" >
```

We can have multiple style tags into our content. What is the simplest way to solve it?

Comment: Why is it tagged java, do you intend to run the regexs from a java environment? Also do you really need to use regex to achieve your goal? Because while a regex solution probably is possible, it really isn't an appropriate tool for this task.

Comment: @Aaron I am using Jsoup in Java to parse it to the Dom. But this quotes in the style cause strange style after parsing. So I need to remove them before parsing. Is there a better way than RegEx?

Comment: I was thinking of something that would act as a context-aware parser, but even then I'm not sure how to describe what distinguishes the `"` that closes your style attribute from the ones that need to be removed. In your example it's quite easy (it's the one that precedes the `>` ), but if you have other attributes on the same line (which can have a `="value"` or not), or your attribute's value is split on multiple lines, it can make things more complicated.

Comment: @Aaron Yes you are right. Other attributes is the complex part of the problem. I don't know how it is rendered by chrome at all

Answer (score 0):

Remove double quotes in Java:

```
String firstAdjustment = input.replaceAll("\"(?!\\s>)", "");
String result = firstAdjustment.replaceAll("=", "=\"");
```

Regexs in context and testbench:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<span style=\"color: rgb(34 , 34 , 34) ; font-family: \"arial\" , \"verdana\" ,"
            + " \"helvetica\" , sans-serif ; font-size: 15.33px ; font-weight: normal\" >";

    String firstAdjustment = input.replaceAll("\"(?!\\s>)", "");
    String result = firstAdjustment.replaceAll("=", "=\"");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
<span style="color: rgb(34 , 34 , 34) ; font-family: arial , verdana , helvetica , sans-serif ; font-size: 15.33px ; font-weight: normal" >
```

Reference to "Special constructs":

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html